# how to get /validate total value from dynamic text field?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic text field whose HTML markup looks like this:

```
<INPUT type="text" name="txt[]" id ="txt[]"/>
```

How would I get the total dynamic value and validate it using Javascript and PHP?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: It only holds one value, so I guess it's always total, and I don't think the value can be dynamic? I guess you do `$('#txt\[\]').val()`

Comment: @JohnConde Your auto-comment is broken; it appears to be `$SITEURL$`, not `$siteurl$`.

Comment: @Waleed Khan, thx. I copied it from the wrong note in Evernote.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be some trigger for when you check the value to validate it, but you can get the value using jQuery with `.val`

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
    if ($(this).find('[name^=txt]').val() == '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('empty');
    }
})
```